# Understand Function Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand this code.

```js
function printEven(arr, pow) {
    var res = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
        res = res * arr;
    }  
    return res;
}

console.log(printEven(4,3))
```

Comment: This implements a subset of [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) functionality, but the name of the function and variables is rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it is just a custom implementation of an exponential function.

It effectively calculates `arr^pow`, or in this case `4**3` or `4 * 4 * 4`.

At `i = 0`, res gets multiplied with arr, `1 * 4 = 4`. 
At `i = 2` it will have calculated `4 * 4 * 4`, returning **64**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printEven(arr, pow) {
var res = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < pow; i++){
    
        res = res * arr;
    }  
    return res;
}

console.log(printEven(4,3))
console.log(printEven(5,2))
```

This code is to find "number ^ times"

example 4 ^ 3 = 4 * 4 * 4 = 64

[https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RBAS_OEXPONENT#:~:text=Used%20to%20raise%20a%20number%20to%20the%20power%20of%20an%20exponent.](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RBAS_OEXPONENT#:%7E:text=Used%20to%20raise%20a%20number%20to%20the%20power%20of%20an%20exponent.)